# Compilation error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: compilation, fortran, fft, fftw

I am trying to use a fortran library to perform FFT called "2Decomp&FFT"(http://www.2decomp.org/download.html). This library has a in-built FFT engine and works fine with my code. In order to use FFTW3 engine with this library, instead of its in-built engine, the instructions say:

> Edit 'src/Makefile.inc' file in 2DECOMP, change the FFT engine to 'FFT=fftw3'. You also need to set the FFTW_PATH variable in the same file to point to your FFTW installation. Then recompile everything.

I installed FFTW3.3 on my local Mac and followed the instructions and recompiled the library. However after that when I am trying to compile my code with the library, I am getting the following error while linking.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_dfftw_destroy_plan_", referenced from:
  ___decomp_2d_fft_MOD_decomp_2d_fft_finalize in lib2decomp_fft.a(fft_fftw3.o)
"_dfftw_execute_dft_", referenced from:
  ___decomp_2d_fft_MOD_c2c_1m_z in lib2decomp_fft.a(fft_fftw3.o)
  ___decomp_2d_fft_MOD_c2c_1m_x in lib2decomp_fft.a(fft_fftw3.o)
  ___decomp_2d_fft_MOD_c2c_1m_y in lib2decomp_fft.a(fft_fftw3.o)
"_dfftw_execute_dft_c2r_", referenced from:
  ___decomp_2d_fft_MOD_c2r_1m_x in lib2decomp_fft.a(fft_fftw3.o)
  ___decomp_2d_fft_MOD_fft_3d_c2r in lib2decomp_fft.a(fft_fftw3.o)
"_dfftw_execute_dft_r2c_", referenced from:
  ___decomp_2d_fft_MOD_fft_3d_r2c in lib2decomp_fft.a(fft_fftw3.o)
"_dfftw_plan_many_dft_", referenced from:
  ___decomp_2d_fft_MOD_c2c_1m_z_plan in lib2decomp_fft.a(fft_fftw3.o)
  ___decomp_2d_fft_MOD_c2c_1m_x_plan in lib2decomp_fft.a(fft_fftw3.o)
  ___decomp_2d_fft_MOD_c2c_1m_y_plan in lib2decomp_fft.a(fft_fftw3.o)
"_dfftw_plan_many_dft_c2r_", referenced from:
  ___decomp_2d_fft_MOD_init_fft_engine in lib2decomp_fft.a(fft_fftw3.o)
"_dfftw_plan_many_dft_r2c_", referenced from:
  ___decomp_2d_fft_MOD_init_fft_engine in lib2decomp_fft.a(fft_fftw3.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Sora_v71] Error 1
```

Here is a minimal code I have written which calls this library:
      program  test

```
  use decomp_2d
  use decomp_2d_fft

  integer n, pr, pc

  call decomp_2d_init(n,n,n,pr,pc)
  call decomp_2d_fft_init

  stop
  end
```

Here is the Makefile I am using (DECOMP2D is the environment variable set to the folder containing the library) :

```
## ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Lines included for using the 2decomp libraries

INC_2DECOMP = -I$(DECOMP2D)/include/
LIB_2DECOMP = -L$(DECOMP2D)/lib/ -l2decomp_fft

## ------------------------------------------------------------------------

RM           =  rm
SRCDIR       = .
LIBDIR       = .

BIN          = a.out
OBJS         = main.o 

## ------------------------------------------------------------------------

# default command for compiler, linker
FC       =  mpif90

FFLAGS   = $(F90FLAG) $(INC_2DECOMP)
LFLAGS   = $(F90FLAG) $(LIB_2DECOMP) -L$(LIBDIR)

## ------------------------------------------------------------------------

# default action
all: $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJS)
@echo Linking $(BIN) .....
$(FC) $(OBJS)  $(LFLAGS) $(FFLAGS) -o $@ 

.f.o:
@echo Compiling $*.f
$(FC)  $(LFLAGS) $(FFLAGS) -c $(SRCDIR)/$*.f

clean:
@echo 'Cleaning .....'
$(RM) -f core *.o *~ *.L *.O $(BIN) $(SIZE_FILE)
```

Comment: It looks suspiciously like you have a 32 bit version of FFTW3. Use `otool` to look at the Mach headers and symbol list in your copy of FFTW3. The answer is probably there

Comment: sorry but I am not able to figure out how to use this "otool" tool. how can I use it to determine the version of FFTW3?

Comment: I used "otool -hV libfftw3.a" and it shows x86_64 in cputype. So I guess it is the 64 bit version of FFTW3.

Comment: Have a look at the symbol table. I note that there are a mixture of symbols with a single leading underscore and with three. It might be a different symbol mangling convention. What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am sorry but what is the symbol table? I am not sure about the compiler I am using. I downloaded fftw-3.3.3 from the official page and just did "./configure --with-g77-wrappers", "make", "make install" to install fftw3. To compile my code I am using mpif90.

Comment: mpif90 is not a compiler, it is only a wrapper around a compiler, which is why I asked. I can see the mpif90 calls in the makefile, but that doesn't tell me what compiler you are using. You can use `otool -TV` to print out the symbol list

Comment: $mpif90 -show
gfortran -I/usr/local/include -Wl,-commons,use_dylibs -I/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lmpi_f90 -lmpi_f77 -lmpi -lm

Comment: I should use "otool -TV" on which file?